# Is it possible to setup magento databse without the php files stucture?

Tags: database

I have the following archtecture to a simple load balance magento store that I made with NGINX.

So far I have created a round-robin mechanism with NGINX in mySIte.com that redirects the client (user) to the srvMag-1, srvMag-2, srvMag-n,srvMag-1, srvMag-2, srvMag-n, ...,  etc (round-robin).

As I am not specilalist in Magento (I am a begginer), my point now is if it is possible to create a server to deal only with the magento databse? The idea is to set srvMag-1, srvMag-2, srvMag-n point to that server db.

If is that possible how to setup only a databse for magento, without to setup the php files and in the other hand how to setup only the magento php files without the database?

To be clear:

1. In **srvMag-1**, **srvMag-2**, **srvMag-n** I will only need the complete structure (php files, etc) but I dont want the database.
2. In **srvDB** I only need the databse, but not the complete structure (php files, etc).

[image]

Comment: You can just put the files on srvMag1 then install it normally and on the database setup step fill in the credentials for your DB machine. Then copy/rsync/whatever the files from srvMag1 to srvMag2 & 3. Some other changes might be needed to make the 3 servers use the same media folder for example.

Comment: hi Marius, I think that is what I would like to avoid.  'make the 3 servers use the same media folder'. My idea was to create each server independent to avoid overload the server.  I must syncronize the every media file beetwen the server in the way they could be independent. But as I told, this is only my though as a programmer.  I am just a begginer in Magento. Am I wrong? So your proposition is to install the db server as a regular magento instalation and make each other server to point to it. Correct?

Comment: If you don't want to share the images then ignore my previous comment after ' from srvMag1 to srvMag2 & 3'. Not sure about it but it should work like I explained. You can give it a try

Comment: ok I wil try it.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple

**Fresh Install:**

Point the same database while setup magento2 [GUI or CLI]

**Already Installed:**

If you already Installed Just change the configuration file to point same db in both magento instance.

You need to change in `<magento-root>/app/etc/env.php`

```
'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'db-server-host',
        'dbname' => 'db-name',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'model' => 'mysql4',
        'engine' => 'innodb',
        'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
),
```

### update

- There is no condition **DB server and magento instance** in same machine
- You can use database server remotely

**My Setup**

I hope this will point you right direction

I have setup like **two magento instance** + **one database** with **shared redis session and cache** + **shared nfs media folder**. It works like charm for me.

If you need any clarity, feel free to mention in comment.

Comment: hi Bilal, let me see if I got, so you mean, I must to install magento in my server DB, as a regular instalation, then install magento to each server 1, 2,3,n, and then make each on the previus server to point to the database server. Is it?

Comment: I updated my answer, please review @zwitterion

Comment: yes it seems to be exactlly what I am doing. nd what I need to do.